# Can someone create a Bitcoin address that is identical to another except the last letter is lowercase where mine is capital

Tags: address-generation

The reason I ask is an online casino was set to pay me $1,000 via Bitcoin and showed me the address they claim to have paid, which is identical to mine except the very last letter is capital and on mine it's a lower case. Is it possible to create another address so similar to mine?

Comment: Ask them for the txnid (transaction id, aka transaction hash) and look that up (or if willing post it for others to do so)

Comment: Thank you. I know it sounds like a stupid question to you guys but I feel I'm being lied to by these guys and just wanted to clarify before I pursue my funds any further. They said only finance dept has that info and of course they never return my calls, msgs, emails ect...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have two valid Bitcoin addresses that differ only in their last 5 characters at all, as those only contain checksum data. For bech32/bech32m addresses (bc1...), that's even true for the last 6 characters.

In theory, it *is* possible to construct two P2PKH (1...) or P2SH (3...) addresses that differ only in 1 character if not at the very end, but the probability is very low that any given addresses has such a valid mutation (1 in ~75 million). With bech32/bech32m any two valid address differ in at least 5 characters.

Comment: Where do you get ~100million? Odds against the check being the same is 2^32 which is just over 4billion. And that's only after you found two pubkeys, or scripts, that hashed to near-identical values, which is only a little less than the birthday bound, maybe 2^120 against i.e. won't happen in this universe.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 2^32 / 57 (because there are 57 distinct single-position errors). And by valid I meant "checksum valid", ignoring whether anyone else might have the private key for it. This is what matters for not accidentally sending your coins into the void.

Comment: So to clarify if they "allegedly" made a deposit to the address they claim, what exactly would happen?

Comment: @Jerry Nothing, that would not be a valid address, and there is no way to send anything to it. Either their software is horribly broken, or they are lying.